# How do I get the jQuery button css to toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, laravel

I'm working on an inherited site which I upgraded from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 8. It has a lot of jQuery and all the js and css is pre-processed. One button that is supposed to change color when it is clicked doesn't work. This is the jQuery function for that button:

```js
define([], function () {
  var VipClass = function () {
    // Private vars
    var _this = this;
    // Private Methods
    var _construct = function () {
      $(document).on('click', '.button-vip', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
  
        var t = $(e.currentTarget),
            url = t.data('url'),
            status = !t.hasClass('btn-glow');
  
        t.prop('disabled', true);
  
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
          data: {
            status: status
          },
          dataType: 'JSON',
          async: true,
          cache: false,
          complete: function () {
            t.prop('disabled', false);
          },
          success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
              t.toggleClass('btn-clean', !status);
              t.toggleClass('btn-glow', status);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    };
    // Init
    _construct();
  };

  return VipClass;
});
```

That's the prettified version of the code. The button either has orange fill if activated or no fill if not. In either case the jQuery doesn't change it when clicked. If I refresh the page or go out and come back the change has been applied so I know the save to the db is working. The ajax success appears to be doing a double toggle.

This is the html of the button:

```xml
<button class="button-vip btn btn-warning btn-icon btn-sm btn-glow" data-url="...">
  <span class="icon-star"></span>
</button>
```

Probably, my biggest problem is that I don't know how to manually change the code when the files are preprocessed. I have not worked much with pre-processed files and it seems cumbersome to have to continually re-compile for a small change. How is this generally handled in dev?

Comment: if I'm understanding correctly typically you would have a gulp or grunt file that has a watch task. watch looks for any changes to your files and automatically re-compiles

Comment: We can't possibly help with this problem unless we know what the HTML looks like and what the ajax response is. It would also be nice to see the unprocessed code so we don't have to try and parse `a` and `n`...

Comment: I replaced the jQuery code with the original and added the html of the button. I could set up the watch task with the gulp preprocessor except that the preprocessing is done on a local machine and then code pushed to the server.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Do you have an error message? Does the ajax request work?

Comment: "The button either has orange fill if activated or no fill if not. In either case the jQuery doesn't change it when clicked. If I refresh the page or go out and come back the change has been applied so I know the save to the db is working. "